# java multi class paint

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, paint

I am working in a project with graphics where so far I have 2 different classes with graphics in each one. In both classes the `paint(Graphics g)` method is called but when I execute it, both `JFrames` are flickering.

My question: is that the correct way is to call all the graphics of the project in one class or new threads for each class are required?

Thank you in advance.

---

#### Code snippets

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    repaint(); 
    mapLimits();
    moveEnemy();
    g.drawImage(background, 0,0, null); // draw background 
    drawImage(g, myHero, heroXposition, heroYposition, "name"); // draw hero 
    repaint(); 
}
```

and for the inventory class the paint method goes like this

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    g.drawImage(background, 0,0,null); //background 
    repaint(); 
}
```

and both of them are called in the main class

```
Hero hero = new Hero(); 
hero.setVisible(true); 
Inventory inv = new Inventory(); 
inv.setVisible();
```

Comment: Your question as stated is extremely vague.  Care to share some code and point to something specific that doesn't work?

Comment: Of course. 
the first class is called map where the paint method is
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
repaint();
mapLimits();
moveEnemy();
g.drawImage(background, 0,0, null); // draw background
drawImage(g, myHero, heroXposition, heroYposition, "name"); // draw hero
repaint();

and for the inventory class the paint method goes like this
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawImage(background, 0,0,null); //background
repaint();
}
and both of them are called in the main class 
Hero hero = new Hero();
hero.setVisible(true);

Inventory inv = new Inventory();
inv.setVisible();

Comment: Scratch 'some code' and descriptions of code in comment form, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  One thing an SSCCE Would have told me, is the parent class of `map` and whether it should implement `paint(Graphics)` or `paintComponent(Graphics)`.  BTW - class names should be `EachWordUpperCase`.

Comment: Never call `repaint()` from within `paint(Graphics)`!  It seems you are attempting 'coding by magic' - that will not work.

Comment: yes but if i do not call repaint() from withing paint(Graphics), the images are not updated (position on the screen or animation) unless i minimize and re-open the JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has nothing to do with `Thread` (or rather, throwing threads at this will not solve the problems the code already has).  It all comes down to custom painting, and doing it correctly.

See the [Performing Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) lesson of the Java Tutorial for details.

Some general tips are:

- Never override `paint(Graphics)` in a top level container.  The minute you do, you discover that the custom rendering might be better shown in a `JDialog`, `JInternalFrame` (etc.) rather than whatever you coded it in.
- Instead extend one of `JComponent` or `JPanel`.  The first for entirely custom painting, the second if combining custom painting with other components.  In either of those classes, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`.
- Use the common nomenclature for class & method names.  Classes `EachWordUpperCase`, methods & attributes `firstWordLowerCase`, constants `ALL_UPPER_CASE`.  This is especially important if anyone besides you will ever read the code.  Other programmers use the case of names to provide hints as to their nature/source.
- Don't call `repaint()` from within either `paint(Graphics)` **or** `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Comment: thank you a lot for your suggestions. Regarding the name of the class i wrote like this by mistake. Anyway I will read the tutorial and if my problem will be solved, i will accept this answer. thank you